# Append to environment variable for Scala Process

Tags: scala, environment-variables

I can't find an example of *appending* to an environment variable. For example, the code below completely replaces `PATH`. Could someone help me with appending, either directly or by showing me how to access the current `PATH` so that I can then modify itself and pass the fully-modified value to the `Process`

```
val out2 = Process("env", None, "PATH" -> "/usr/local/bin")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's:

```
scala> util.Properties.envOrNone("PATH")
res0: Option[String] = Some(/home/apm/go1.1/go/bin:/home/apm/go/bin:/home/apm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games)
```

That is:

```
scala> util.Properties.envOrSome("PATH", Some("")) map (p => s"$p${new sys.SystemProperties()("path.separator")}/tmp") get
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res5: String = /home/apm/go1.1/go/bin:/home/apm/go/bin:/home/apm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/tmp
```

I just noticed my PATH has gone stale.

Edit for idiom:

```
scala> def appendToEnv(key: String, value: String) = util.Properties.envOrNone(key) match {
     |   case Some(v) if v.nonEmpty => s"$v${System getProperty "path.separator"}$value"
     |   case _ => value
     | }
appendToEnv: (key: String, value: String)String

scala> appendToEnv("PATH", "/opt")
res0: String = /home/apm/go1.1/go/bin:/home/apm/go/bin:/home/apm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt

scala> appendToEnv("UNPATH", "/opt")
res1: String = /opt
```

Comment: Woohoo, exactly what I needed. Funny you answered the other question on this topic too :-P

Comment: Life is funny.  I added what I think is more idiomatic code. It also handles `Some("")` as edge case.